# Calling destroy on relation in Mongoid many to many relation with helper model does not remove model from List

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have a many to many relation from User to Project with a `helper` model. User and Project has many `user_project_memberships` and `user_project_membership` has one Project and one User.
When I try to remove a relation from project's `related_users` (or from user's related_projects) data will be removed from database correctly but related_users array still has that relation data!

```
  def remove_user(uid)
    rel = self.related_users.where(user_id: uid)[0]
    if rel
      rel.destroy
      self.related_users.delete(rel) # Added this to remove that relation manually
    end
  end
```

`project.related_users.count` return correct amount of relations for project but this code not doing what expected!

```
project.related_users.each do |user|
     puts user.id
end
```

If `project.related_users.count` shows `4` the small code above prints `hello` 5 times!

Any help appreciated, to know what really happened!

PS : I'm not expert in ruby, It's maybe ruby's problem!

Comment: I think relation should be user_project_membership belongs_to Project and belongs_to User

Comment: Current database relation is : User <- user_project_membership -> Project (-> is 1-N relation)

Comment: What are the columns in user_project_memberships table?

Comment: project_id, user_id,rate , ...